# Excel formula, counting number of cells since last non zero

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a number of columns indicating sales per month for example the following might indicate that two months ago there was a sale from this customer of $3555.

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3555,0,0
```

I need a formula to calculate the number of months since the last sale, i.e. the result in this case should be 2.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating further Jook's answer:

Assume that the sales values for months 1 to 12 are located in cells A1:L1.

We can use an array formula to find the desired result:

```
=COLUMN(L1)-MAX(IF(A1:L1>0,COLUMN(A1:L1),0))
```

Enter the formula and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
to designate it as an array formula. 
Excel will automatically display curly braces:

```
{=COLUMN(L1)-MAX(IF(A1:L1>0,COLUMN(A1:L1),0))}
```

(Do not type the braces.)

This creates a virtual array that holds
the column numbers for the cells where sales are greater than zero
and finds the greatest column number
(i.e., closest to the end of the reporting period). 
Then we need to subtract this value from number of the last column.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an quick solution for this. However, you need a helper row, which means, there is room for improvement. Maybe someone else can take it from here.

This is the setup:

```
month 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
sale  0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 8 11 0  0 
help  0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 9 10 0  0
```

help-formula:

```
IF(SALE>0,MONTH,0) - IF(A2>0,A1,0)
```

months since last sale:

```
MAX(A1:L1)-MATCH(MAX(A3:L3);A3:L3;0)
```

The main problem is to get to the max column number with a sale value greater than 0. Right now, I can only think of VBA & Matrix-Function to solve this without the helper-row. But I have the feeling I am missing something.